# Display div when container overflow is hidden

Tags: html, reactjs

I have a `div`containing a lot of elements, so I must use a `scroll`. The idea is to show a popup on div's `hover`. But `overflow: hidden` is not enough to show popup. I tried many ways but failed and I run out of ideas.

This is my code:
https://codepen.io/Danica1986/pen/gVjvva?editors=0110

```
class Content extends React.Component {


  render() {
    return (
   <div className="footer">
    <div className="footer-content">
        <div className="scene-list-contnet">
            <div className="list-slide-items">
                <div className="item-with-scene">
                    <div className="scene-placeholder">
                        <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1490077476659-095159692ab5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=500&q=60" className="scene-img" />
                        <div className="open-scene-options"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/minimalist-arrows-set/100/ARROW-expand__up_arrow-512.png"/></div>

                        <div className="scene-options">
                            <ul>
                                <li>Option 1</li>
                                <li>Option 2</li>
                                <li>Option 3</li>
                                <li>Option 4</li>
                                <li>Option 5</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
    );
  }
}

React.render(<Content />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```
.footer 
    width: calc(100% - 64px) 
    height: 150px 
    position: fixed 
    top: 250px 
    background: #fff 
    margin-left: 64px 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 
.scene-list-contnet 
    width: calc(100% - 92px) 
    float: right 
    height: 100px 
    overflow-y: scroll 

.footer 
    .list-slide-items 
        margin: 7px 0px 
        list-style-type: none 
        display: -webkit-inline-box 
        display: -ms-inline-flexbox 
        display: inline-flex 
        -webkit-box-orient: horizontal 
        -webkit-box-direction: normal 
        -ms-flex-direction: row 
        flex-direction: row 
        margin-bottom: 0 
    .item-with-scene 
        width: 145px 
        height: 82px 
        margin-right: 15px 
        display: inline-block 
    .scene-placeholder 
        position: relative 
        width: 100% 
        padding-top: 56.25% 
.scene-placeholder 
    img 
        max-width: 100% 
    .open-scene-options 
        position: absolute 
        width: 21px 
        top: 5px 
        right: 5px 
        background: #fff 
        z-index: 3 
        border-radius: 100% 
        text-align: center 
        -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 
        transition: all 0.2s linear 
        cursor: pointer 
    visibility: hidden
        img 
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) 
            transform: rotate(180deg) 
            width: 8px 
            -webkit-transition-duration: 1s 
            transition-duration: 1s 
            -webkit-transition-property: -webkit-transform 
            transition-property: -webkit-transform 
            transition-property: transform 
            transition-property: transform, -webkit-transform 
        &:hover 
            img 
                -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) 
                transform: rotate(360deg) 
            & + .scene-options 
                visibility: visible 
    &:hover 
        .open-scene-options 
            visibility: visible 
.list-slide-items 
    .scene-placeholder 
        .scene-img 
            max-width: 100% 
            max-height: 100% 
            width: 100% 
            position: absolute 
            top: 0 
            bottom: 0 
            left: 0 
            right: 0 
            z-index: 1 
            cursor: pointer 
            opacity: 0.6 
            -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear 
            transition: all 0.2s linear 
            &:hover 
                opacity: 1 
.scene-options 
    width: 141px 
    height: 165px 
    position: absolute 
    z-index: 11 
    background: #fff 
    bottom: 90px 
    left: 63px 
    background: #fff 
    border-radius: 18px 
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) 
    padding: 12px 17px 

    &:hover 
        visibility: visible 
    &:after 
        content: "" 
        width: 0px 
        height: 0px 
        position: absolute 
        border-left: 10px solid transparent 
        border-right: 10px solid transparent 
        border-top: 10px solid #fff 
        border-bottom: 10px solid transparent 
        left: 57px 
        bottom: -20px 
    ul 
        list-style-type: none 
        margin-bottom: 0 
.open-scene-options 
    &:hover 
        .scene-options 
            visibility: visible
```

Comment: Check this - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars

Comment: may be my mistake, but I dont understand your requirement completely

Comment: https://codepen.io/Danica1986/pen/gVjvva?editors=0110 This is edit code

Comment: https://prnt.sc/oqh4b5 
the results of my code, but i need like this https://prnt.sc/oqh58o

Comment: I tried this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-custom-scrollbars , but it's the same problem